# ERROR in ESB 4.5.0: User name not provided for the Entitlement mediator

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I´m working with a backend service in AS 5.0.1, that it´s exposed to the outside using ESB 4.5.0 with a UT security policy. this proxy service use an entitlement mediator to validated the user authorization to access to this service, so I use the IS 4.0.0.
This scenario work fine with previous wso2 product versions.

I implemented this scenario in my laptop with IS 3.2.3 and it work fine. now when I uploaded the configuration to the production servers I saw this error:
NOTE: in the production servers I used  two tenant for AS and ESB.

The error:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,787] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator} -  org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: User name not provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,791]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,791]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : User name not provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,791]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: User name not provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator.mediate(EntitlementMediator.java:135)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:60)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.doSOAP(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:233)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.processRequest(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.MultitenantMessageReceiver.receive(MultitenantMessageReceiver.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,792]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: User name not provided for the Entitlement mediator - can't proceed {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,793]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  FaultHandler : org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler@563ac83c {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,793]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler} -  Executing fault handler mediator : fault {org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-14 00:14:43,794]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: local://axis2services/Profesor_Proxy.Profesor_ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint, WSAction: http://cdae.uci.cu/servicios/Servicio_Profesor/obtenerDatosProfesor, SOAPAction: http://cdae.uci.cu/servicios/Servicio_Profesor/obtenerDatosProfesor, MessageID: urn:uuid:D4E74AEA911A3C697B1352870083848, Direction: request, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prof="http://cdae.uci.cu/schemas/Profesor"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-20"><wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*****</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Rs/AfaxxkrPr6FbTKaKUUg==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2012-11-14T05:14:46.624Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-19"><wsu:Created>2012-11-14T05:14:46.623Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2012-11-14T05:48:06.623Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security><wsa:Action>http://cdae.uci.cu/servicios/Servicio_Profesor/obtenerDatosProfesor</wsa:Action><wsa:MessageID>uuid:20a1b0e1-43f6-49ab-b523-8da4b36043ad</wsa:MessageID><wsa:To>https://server:8243/services/t/ptesisesb.cdae.uci.cu/Profesor_Proxy.Profesor_ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint</wsa:To></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body>
      <prof:obtenerDatosProfesor>
         <prof:solapin>****</prof:solapin>
      </prof:obtenerDatosProfesor>
   </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope> {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

my soap message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prof="http://cdae.uci.cu/schemas/Profesor">   
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-20">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">****</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Rs/AfaxxkrPr6FbTKaKUUg==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2012-11-14T05:14:46.624Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
         <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-19">
            <wsu:Created>2012-11-14T05:14:46.623Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2012-11-14T05:48:06.623Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
      <wsa:Action>http://cdae.uci.cu/servicios/Servicio_Profesor/obtenerDatosProfesor</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:20a1b0e1-43f6-49ab-b523-8da4b36043ad</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:To>https://server:8243/services/t/ptesisesb.cdae.uci.cu/Profesor_Proxy.Profesor_ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint</wsa:To>
   </soapenv:Header>   
   <soapenv:Body>      
      <prof:obtenerDatosProfesor>         
         <prof:solapin>*****</prof:solapin>      
      </prof:obtenerDatosProfesor>   
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Profesor_Proxy" transports="https" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="conf:/secuenciasutiles/log_seguridad_mejorado" outSequence="conf:/gestion_tesis/servicioProfesor/secuencias/centralAssetsOUT" faultSequence="fault"/>
   <publishWSDL key="conf:/gestion_tesis/servicioProfesor/wsdl/Servicio_Profesor1.wsdl"/>
   <parameter name="addressingRequirementParameter">required</parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

and the sequence with the entitlement mediator inside:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" onError="conf:/secuenciasutiles/falla_de_conexion">
   <entitlementService remoteServiceUrl="https://server:9448/services/" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="*****" onReject="conf:/secuenciasutiles/log_cuando_no_pasa" onAccept="conf:/secuenciasutiles/log_cuando_pasa" advice=""/>
</sequence>
```

In this sequence I also see that the onAccept sequence disappear time to time.

What could be the problem? I use the UT policy and I see the username in the incoming message to the ESB.

I can fix this error but now I´m facing another one. I have the same configuration in different servers in one it work, in the another one not. 
in this particular case i see the request/response in the IS 4.0.0 with the Permit value so the entitlement work.

the error:

```
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,359] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender} -  Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No user value in the rampart configuration policy
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:193)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:445)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:281)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: No user value in the rampart configuration policy
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.addUsernameToken(BindingBuilder.java:210)
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.build(TransportBindingBuilder.java:95)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:140)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:106)
        ... 21 more
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,366]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,367]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,367]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:170)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:69)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:281)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingMethod(ServerWorker.java:409)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: No user value in the rampart configuration policy
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:193)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:445)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: No user value in the rampart configuration policy
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.addUsernameToken(BindingBuilder.java:210)
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.TransportBindingBuilder.build(TransportBindingBuilder.java:95)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:140)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:106)
        ... 21 more
 {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,368]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
TID: [] [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus] [2012-11-15 20:10:49,368]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} -  FaultHandler : Endpoint [conf/HelloServiceAS] {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jorge,

The error usually comes when the entitlement mediator is unable to extract the username of the user who's trying to access the target resource. Retrieving the username of a particular user is done by an appropriate entitlement callback handler implementation (by processing headers, etc). 
However, try explicitly setting entitlement callback handler parameter to "org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.callback.UTEntitlementCallbackHandler" which corresponds to retrieving the username of the user when UT is applied to a particular service. (AFAIR, value of the parameter entitlement callback handler used to have the default value to be the one mentioned above). Anyway, try setting it in the entitlement service mediator configuration as follows.

```
<entitlementService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9443/services/" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="admin" callbackClass="org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.callback.UTEntitlementCallbackHandler"/>
```

Cheers,
Prabath

Comment: Hi prabath, thanks for answer. after fix that error i have another one, please see my question for an update.